# Exact Successor State Distribution for a Pendulum

Tags: probability, distributions, convolution, transform, differential-equations

I want to solve the following problem. Suppose we have a simple pendulum, which follows the differential equation
\begin{equation}
 \dot{x} = f(x) = [x_2, -\sin(x_1)]^T, \text{with } x=[x_1, x_2]^T.
\end{equation}
Given an inital state the successor state is calculated via eulers method
\begin{equation}
 x_{k+1} = x_k + \Delta t f(x_k), \text{where we use } \Delta t = 1 \text{ for simplicity}.
\end{equation}
Given $x_k \sim \mathcal{N}(m, S)$, what is the exact distribution of the successor state?

My solution looks like this and is divided into 2 steps.

Step 1) Transform $x \to \dot{x}$ and get $p(\dot{x})$

Step 2) Assume independence and use the convolution rule based on $p(x_k)$ and $p(\dot{x}_k)$

---

Step 1) We need to solve
\begin{equation}
 p(\dot{x}) = p(x = f^{-1}(\dot{x})) \bigg| \frac{d f^{-1}(\dot{x})}{d \dot{x}} \bigg|.
\end{equation}
The inverse function gives
\begin{equation}
 f^{-1}(\dot{x}; k, i) = 
 \begin{cases} 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \pi + \arcsin \bigl(\dot{x}_2 \bigr) + 2 \pi k & \dot{x}_1
  \end{bmatrix}^T, \\ 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   2 \pi k - \arcsin \bigl( \dot{x}_2 \bigr) & \dot{x}_1
  \end{bmatrix}^T,
 \end{cases}
 k \in \mathbb{Z}, -1 \leq \dot{x}_2 \leq 1,
\end{equation}
and the absolute determinante of the jacobian is
\begin{equation}
 \bigg| \frac{d f^{-1}(\dot{x})}{d \dot{x}} \bigg| 
 = 
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{ |\dot{x}_2^2 - 1| } }, \quad \dot{x}_2 \neq 1.
\end{equation}
In total we have
\begin{equation}
 p(\dot{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{2} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{p(f^{-1}(\dot{x}); k, i)}{ \sqrt{ |\dot{x}_2^2 - 1| } }.
\end{equation}

Here's my matlab code

```
% - cleanup
clear;
close all;
clc;

% - symbolic variables
syms x1 x2 xp1 xp2 real
x = [x1; x2];
xp = [xp1; xp2];
sol = solve(xp == [x2; -sin(x1)], x, 'ReturnConditions', true);
x1 = sol.x1
x2 = sol.x2
sol.conditions
absdetjac = abs(det(jacobian([x1(1); x2(1)], xp)))

% - grid
grid0.n = 500;
grid0.x1lim = [-10, 10];
grid0.x2lim = [-10, 10];
grid0.x1 = linspace(grid0.x1lim(1), grid0.x1lim(2), grid0.n);
grid0.x2 = linspace(grid0.x2lim(1), grid0.x2lim(2), grid0.n);
grid0.A = (grid0.x1(2)-grid0.x1(1))*(grid0.x2(2)-grid0.x2(1));
[grid0.X1, grid0.X2] = meshgrid(grid0.x1, grid0.x2);
grid0.Xv = [grid0.X1(:), grid0.X2(:)]';

% - initial state distribution
mx = [pi, 0]';
Sx = [2, 0; 0, 0.5];
Lx = chol(Sx)';
grid0.pX = reshape(mvnpdf(grid0.Xv', mx', Sx)', grid0.n, grid0.n);

% - state derivative distribution
fcn = @(x) [x(2, :); -sin(x(1, :))];

invfcn = @(xp, k, i) (i==1)*[pi + asin(xp(2, :)) + 2*pi*k; xp(1, :)] + ...
                     (i==2)*[2*pi*k - asin(xp(2, :)); xp(1, :)];

absdetjacfcn = @(xp) 1./abs(xp(2, :).^2 - 1).^(1/2);

grid0.iok = abs(grid0.Xv(2, :)) <= 1;       % error maybe here?
grid0.k = -3 : 3;
grid0.i = 1 : 2;
grid0.pXpki = zeros(grid0.n, grid0.n, length(grid0.k), length(grid0.i));
for i = 1 : length(grid0.i)
    for j = 1 : length(grid0.k)
        tmp = mvnpdf(...
            invfcn(grid0.Xv, grid0.k(j), grid0.i(i))', mx', Sx) .* ...
            absdetjacfcn(grid0.Xv)';
        tmp(~grid0.iok) = 0;
        grid0.pXpki(:, :, j, i) = reshape(tmp, grid0.n, grid0.n);
    end
end
grid0.pXp = sum(grid0.pXpki, [3, 4]);
grid0.pXX = conv2(grid0.pX, grid0.pXp, 'same');

% - monte carlo approach for reference
seed = 510;
rng(seed);

ns = 150;
nx = 2;
Xs = mx + Lx*randn(nx, ns);
Xps = fcn(Xs);
XXs = Xs + Xps;

% - visualization
figure(1);
subplot(1, 3, 1);
grid on;
hold on;
plot(Xs(1, :), Xs(2, :), 'r.');
contour(grid0.X1, grid0.X2, grid0.pX);

subplot(1, 3, 2);
grid on;
hold on;
plot(Xps(1, :), Xps(2, :), 'r.');
contour(grid0.X1, grid0.X2, grid0.pXp);

subplot(1, 3, 3);
grid on;
hold on;
plot(XXs(1, :), XXs(2, :), 'r.');
contour(grid0.X1, grid0.X2, grid0.pXX);
```

The result is
[image]
left: initial state distribution, middle, state derivative distribution, right: successor state distribution.

As you can see, somethings is not quite right. Where is the problem/mistake?

Comment: Where does $p(x)$ suddenly come from and why do you need it?

Comment: Could you provide a better explanation of your graphs. The point are simulations and the lines are your theoretical distribution density? (So what is wrong is that your simulation doesn't correspond to your theoretic computation?)

Comment: *"Assume independence and use the convolution rule"* how are $x$ and $\dot{x}$ independent?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus sorry, probably messed things up, $p(x)$ is equal to $p(x_k)$. yes, lines are theory and points come from a monte carlo simulation (so basically indicate ground truth). good point, independence assumption might be the problem, however, i've no intuition how strict it is. i wouldnt assume its a big deal here.